# Why doesn't function variable initialize correctly in this example?

Tags: python

Executing the following code:

```
def foo(b=[]):
    b.append(1)
    print(b)
foo()
foo()
foo()
```

The result is unexpectedly:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Investigating variable "b" memory address for different function calls:

```
def foo(b=[]):
    b.append(1)
    print(id(b))
foo()
foo()
foo()
```

returns the same value three times, whereas apparently variable initialization should create new [] object each time. Could you explain this to me please?

Comment: [Read this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

Comment: Or this: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments